# How to use Consul connect with spring-boot micro-services

Tags: microservices, consul, spring-cloud-consul

can Someone please guide me with the steps to secure micro-service communication with TLS using Consul-connect and side-car proxies. I am using spring-cloud-consul-client to register my micro-service to consul agent.

Kind Regards,